# NumberFormatExeption for in put string "2013"

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I'm trying to parse a csv file and I need to set two variables with the initial period and the final period but it `throws NumberFormatException`

```
String line = null;
int initialPeriod = 0;
int finalPeriod = 0;
double sum = 0;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] splitted = line.split(";");

    int period = Integer.parseInt(splitted[0].split("-")[0]);
    if (period < initialPeriod || initialPeriod == 0) {
        initialPeriod = period;
    }
    if (period > finalPeriod || finalPeriod == 0) {
        finalPeriod = period;
    }
}
```

The date (which is in `splitted[0]`) is formatted like:

year-month-day hour:minute

I need only the year so I `split splitted[0]` with the "-" char and then I convert it to int but it throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2013­"
```

(2013 is the first year of my file)

This is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2013­"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at it.tgi.exercise.parser.MainClassParser.main(MainClassParser.java:21)
```

Comment: Please give us the stacktrace you got. Have a look at [ask] and provide [mcve]

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace **and** a [mcve]

Comment: Why don't you use a real CSV parser like [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)? Most of your issues will be resolved using such parser...

Comment: I guess there is a blank in front of the string, which is missing in your title

Comment: @Jens I think the same - my answer is to add trim() to the parsed `String`

Comment: Place a breakpoint on NumberFormatException, and inspect the variable values in the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Copy/pasting gave me the answer.

You don't have a standard dash in your file, but a special character.

Actually, your field contains `2013\u00AD` (hence a length of 5). The `\u00AD` character is a kind of hyphen, but not really.

Hard-type the dash (`-`) instead in your CSV file.

If you want to parse dates in your CSV, you should make sure you have dates and the format you expect.

For that you should use the following (I assume that you have the standard `<year>-<month>-<day>` format):

**Java 7 and below**

```
 // Define before the loop, but careful to not share in other threads.
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

 // The following lines should be in your loop
 String dateField = ... ; // From CSV

 Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
 Date date= dateFormat.parse(dateField);
 calendar.setTime(date);
 int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

**Java 8**

```
 // Define before the loop.
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;

 // The following lines should be in your loop
 String dateField = ... ; // From CSV

 LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateField, formatter);
 int year = date.getYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
while ((line = br.readLine() )!= null) {
    String [] splitted = line.split(";");

    int period = Integer.parseInt(splitted[0].split("-")[0].trim());
    if( period < initialPeriod || initialPeriod == 0)
        initialPeriod = period;
    if(period > finalPeriod || finalPeriod == 0)
        finalPeriod =period;
}
```

You might suffer from some leading white-signs.

**EDIT**

Could you please add this before parsing: System.out.println(splitted[o].split("-")[0].trim().length()‌​? Give us the result. Is it 4?

The result is 5.

Comment: no it doesn't work! :(

Comment: @untruste Could you please add this before parsing: `System.out.println(splitted[o].split("-")[0].trim().length()`? Give us the result. Is it 4?

Comment: it says that the length it's 5!

Comment: When you copy the the "2013" from your exception you posted, it returns as this in my text editor:
`2013­ ` note that the final space shows up as a "dash" or as `\u00AD` depending on what I copy it into. It is a valid non-whitespace character that's mucking things up.

Comment: @untruste so I believe I solved your problem. Feel free to add the sign to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that there is an **invisible hyphen behind the 3**. Whilst you cannot see it, for the runtime it's just a character as other ones.

Try to select the text **For input string** and do then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow right</kbd>. You will see that the cursor somewhere stays at the same position. That means that there is an not-printed character somewhere.

You might want so sanitize the input you're retrieving. Nobody guarantees you that it's always an unwanted character at the fifth position, it can also be at the first position for example. So be careful using `substring(0, 4)`. If your CSV contains more "false" hyphens instead of the normal ones, you might want to include it in the split pattern:

```
int yearStr = splitted[0].split("[-\u00AD]")[0];
Integer.parseInt(yearStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a blank space because I tried using .length and it says that 2013 has 5 character.
So I used .substring(0,4) and now it worked!

Comment: be careful with it - it can cause problems later.

Comment: You don't solve the issue, you only move it. Your CSV file is incorrect and should be adapted. Rewrite the date properly instead of trying to fix it in the code. Bad data is bad.